# Use of bitset operations in pgfplots y filter code

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to be able to produce plots where the y axis data has been manipulated through bit operations, I have made several attempts but I think this is the closest I have come. I believe the problem is with `\bitsetSetDec{B}{#1}`, if I change this to a constant value it works as expected but attempting to use the y data through `...{#1}` or `...{\pgfmathresult}` just results in all zeros.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bitset}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

      \addplot+[y filter/.append code={%
        \bitsetReset{A}%
        \bitsetReset{B}%
        \bitsetSetDec{A}{128}%
        \bitsetSetDec{B}{#1}% <- Possible source of problem
        \bitsetAnd{A}{B}% A &= B
        \def\pgfmathresult{\bitsetGetDec{A}}%
      }] coordinates{(0,16)(1,130)};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pgfplots` uses the floating point unit (FPU) library of PGF. This has a different internal representation of numbers so you have to convert back and forth.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bitset}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

      \addplot+[y filter/.append code={%
        \bitsetReset{A}%
        \bitsetReset{B}%
        \bitsetSetDec{A}{128}%
        \pgfmathfloattoint{#1}%
        \bitsetSetDec{B}{\pgfmathresult}%
        \bitsetAnd{A}{B}% A &= B
        \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\bitsetGetDec{A}}%
      }] coordinates{(0,16)(1,130)};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```